# Java Script Password Prompt not working with Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a little (very simple and very common) javascript password validating script that I have placed on different web pages..what it does is prompts user for the access key whenever they visit the page on which this script exists.

This is totally working fine with Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera..but somehow not working with Safari browser..is there anything that I am missing?

Here is the Java Script snippet:

```
var password;

var pass1="12345abc";

password=prompt('Please enter the key provided!',' ');

if (password==pass1)
 alert('Access Granted!');
else
 {
 window.location="denied.html";
 }
```

In Safari, it is always taking user to the denied.html page even if the right password is provided..

Comment: What is not not working? [I hope you do not think this is "secure"]

Comment: so the password is visible in the javascript? it's not a good idea since the user has access to it in plain text

Comment: I know this is not secure at all..just a regular password protection thing. In safari browser, when I open the page on which this script is called in the header (which prompts user for the password) and enter the 'right' password, it redirects me to the denied.html page, which is intended for users who input wrong passwords. In other browsers, user provided password is validated and the user is forwarded to the right page. Why this is happening in Safari only that even the correct password is regarded as incorrect?

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: version 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)

Comment: I am willing to bet it is the empty space that you have in there by default. Remove the " "

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/eYHNX/) in Safari 6.0.3

Comment: Works for me in Safari 5.1.7 (6534.57.2)

Comment: in the safari's password prompt? I was thinking on that..but how to deal with it? Also, maybe its an encoding thing..?

Comment: i tried after removing it but it still isnt working..tried trimming the password for whitespaces and then equating with pass1 but again failed..this is with Safari..rest of the browsers working fine.

Answer (score 0):

change

`password=prompt('Please enter the key provided!',' ');`

to

`password=prompt('Please enter the key provided!');`

Comment: It's usually a good idea to also explain why you are suggesting the change that you are, so others can learn from it.